# Why my clipboard have content that I never put there?

Tags: clipboard

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with the KDE environment.

My laptop just shut down from overheating while I was playing minecraft, and when I turned it back on, after a bit, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and it paste `123`.

I never copied this and I have no idea how it got on my clipboard. Should I be alarmed?

Comment: Probably not, but I can't offer you proof.

Comment: Where (in which program) did you pasted?

Comment: If you are using KDE and have Klipper installed (it is by default), then you could look at the last ten entries and see if there is anything there to elucidate. There might not be, but worth a try?

Comment: It's "123" anywhere. Web browser, terminal, skype, kate, etc.

Comment: What happens if you restart your computer? Is the *same* content there? Also, what happens if you copy other characters?

Comment: Klipper's history is empty aside from the 123. I can copy and paste other things fine and they appear in klipper's history now. Restarting doesn't make 123 appear again. I'm just wondering why 123 was there in the first place. It's very odd.

Comment: Well, the most probably is that you pressed a combination of keys and the result was *copy*. You should know that Ctrl+C is not the only way to *copy* content to the clipboard..

Comment: Yeah, if you cannot replicate it, I'm not sure what else it could be…

Comment: Could be he did a 'selection'  and the clipboard tools somehow synced the selection (which you can paste via a middle click) to the clipboard.

Comment: @dr_willis: good thinking. In Klipper, there is an option to synchronise primary selection and the clipboard. Is that on?